# Failed to generate the PDF preview - UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to load pdf to UIWebView from URL. Sometimes PDF is not getting loaded and showing an error message  'Failed to generate the PDF preview'. UIWebView 'didFailLoadWithError' delegate also not getting called. Anybody can help me how to handle this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to load the pdf with some delay

Comment: I didn't get that. Could u please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: webview take time to load the pdf.So call it making some delay like this                                                             [self performSelector:@selector(PDF) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

Comment: What is the use of this?

Comment: I am making url request and tell webview to load it like [webView loadRequest:urlRequest]; and webview will start loading the page from the URL.

Comment: i did like this and not getting any problem, just try the code. and tell me